# Why is there bit shifting when converting to an image from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, qimage, qpixmap

I'm trying to create a QPixmap from a numpy array. The numpy array image is going to be 2D (ie no color info just grayscale).

I'm trying to adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796921/1764089) to my needs however I don't quite understand this line:

```
b = (255 << 24 | a[:,:,0] << 16 | a[:,:,1] << 8 | a[:,:,2]).flatten() # pack RGB values
```

There is some bitshifting going on and some bitwise `or`' ing but I don't quite get it to be honest.

So my dumbed down example is as follows:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1920), np.arange(1080), indexing='ij'); z = np.sin(0.03*x)*np.cos(0.005*y)
imgPNFN = z
if imgPNFN.ndim == 2:
    imgPNFN = imgPNFN[:,:,np.newaxis].repeat(3, 2)
imMin = np.min(imgPNFN)
imDelta = np.max(imgPNFN) - np.min(imgPNFN)
im1 = ((imgPNFN-imMin)/imDelta*255).astype(np.uint32)+1 #<-- had to add 1 for some reason otherwise got weird results...
im2 = 255 << 24 | im1[:,:,0] << 16 | im1[:,:,1] << 8 | im1[:,:,2]
im3 = QtGui.QImage(im2, im2.shape[1], im2.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
```

which seems to work but when my image is lena ie:

```
from scipy.misc import lena
l = sp.misc.lena()
imgPNFN = l
#etc...
```

It doesn't work... I think it's because of my lack of understanding of what the bitshifting is doing... Also, if there is a better way to do the RGB (ie I'm copying things over to pretend I have the same values) if I could avoid that somehow that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you want to know why the bit-shifting and `or`-ing is happening. Well, you need to join the `A[lpha]`, `R[ed]`, `G[reen]`, and `B[lue]` bytes together to form a single integer value. Pixel data is a 2D array of integer; scalar value. They are not tuples of bytes.

[image]

### Example

Color: [***Periwinkle***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periwinkle_%28color%29)

```
A: 255 -> 11111111
R: 204 -> 11001100
G: 204 -> 11001100
B: 255 -> 11111111
```

#### Formula

```
Value = A << 24 | R << 16 | G << 8 | B
```

#### Bit-Math

```
  11111111000000000000000000000000
          110011000000000000000000
                  1100110000000000
 +                        11111111
 ---------------------------------
  11111111110011001100110011111111
```

#### Base conversion

`11111111110011001100110011111111`<sub>`2`</sub> = `4291611903`<sub>`10`</sub>

#### Finally

Based on the bit manipulation above, the color Periwinkle, with 100% opacity in ARGB, has a pixel value of 4,291,611,903.

[image]