# How do I display a 2D numpy.ndarray as a collection of pixel values on a specific QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, arrays, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

How do I display a 2D `numpy.ndarray` as a collection of pixel values on a `QGraphicsView`? `pylab.imshow()` would typically be used at this point if I wasn't trying to make a GUI.

```
frame = array([[ 56.,  57.,  58., ...,  58.,  58.,  58.],
       [ 52.,  58.,  58., ...,  56.,  57.,  59.],
       [ 56.,  55.,  58., ...,  57.,  57.,  58.],
       ..., 
       [ 53.,  55.,  55., ...,  54.,  54.,  53.],
       [ 54.,  57.,  56., ...,  53.,  54.,  59.],
       [ 55.,  57.,  54., ...,  56.,  58.,  57.]])
```

**My attempt:**

```
scene = QGraphicsScene(self)                                            
scene.addPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)))
view = self.graphicsView(scene, self) # Error from this line
self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene, self)
view.show()
```

`TypeError: 'QGraphicsView' object is not callable`. I want to specifically add the scene to the `QGraphicsView` named `graphicsView` that was generated by QT Designer. If I replace the line causing the error with the following

```
view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene, self)
```

Then the image displays, but in the top left of the `QMainWindow` on top of my other widgets. How do I restrict placement to a specific `QGraphicsView`?

Comment: Possibly the same as this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794019/convert-numpy-array-to-pyside-qpixmap

Comment: Wow. Looking at my 2 hour long search history, I never used 'numpy,' only "matrix/array to QGraphicsView" and variations. Anyway, I amended my question. Made progress with that link, but still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around I find this minimalist solution:

```
scene = QGraphicsScene(self)            
scene.addPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)))
self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
```